# How to get discord user id from username using discord API

Tags: php, discord

I'm trying to automate adding users to Guilds after they pay a fee to join a specific server ( Guild ) , In the API documentation this is the only method available to add a user, it requires a user id

```
PUT /guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}
```

The workflow I'm trying to implement is that the user types user's username, pays a fee, and then should be automatically added to the server, the average user will not be able to get user's ID by enabling developer mode on the discord app.

Another possible solution is creating an invite, but all I can find about invites in the API documentation is get and delete invite, I could find an implementation in python [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/async/api.html#discord.Client.create_invite) , but I'm not sure what API method is it calling, and I'm using PHP.

Is there any way I can get the user's ID from the user's username ? and if not, is there any possible way to implement the mentioned workflow ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? The snowflake ID makes the process difficult for sure

Comment: I was only able to create an invite to a channel using this https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-channel-invite

Comment: I actually figured this out. You have to use the API to allow the user to auth. Once they auth, you can get their snowflake ID via the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add someone to the server, you would need to make a discord application, and then go from there. It is very possible and is lots of documentation on it, but you can't join someone to a server without any form of authorization.